# Pandas function max() suddenly stopped working for dates telling:TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Code worked perfectly fine until out of nowhere it told me:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Here were the error occurs:

```
def updateMails(mailCsv):
    mailDf = pd.read_csv (mailCsv, sep =";")
    print (mailDf)
    lastDate = mailDf["date"].max()
```

I did wether change data nor code, what is the thing i may ovverlook ?

Comment: First, convert object type date column to datetime type column: `mailDf["date"] = pd.to_datetime(mailDf["date"])`

Comment: @Bushmaster thanks that helped, it did not solve the problem itself but i know might know why this is happening. It now throws the following error : >ValueError: Time data date is not ISO8601 format, at position 3664. You might want to try:   
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exact    I know checked Index 3664 for my dataframe and the date format is the same as the others, but the dataframe index start there at 0 again so i might this error occured because i appended a DF

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
import pandas as pd

def updateMails(mailCsv):
    backupDf = pd.read_csv(mailCsv, sep=";")
    backupDf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(backupDf['date'], errors='coerce')
    print(backupDf['date'])
    lastDate = backupDf["date"].max()
    return lastDate


lastDate = updateMails('mail.csv')
print('Max Date:', lastDate)
```

Comment: like written in the comment under @Bushmaster the  backupDf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(backupDf['date'], errors='coerce') line helps to identify an error when something with date an pandas function like max() does not worked, in my case it seems i forget to comment some concat/append function out resulting in a wrong dataframe